# JSTL using var in foreach items

Tags: java, spring, jsp, foreach, jstl

I have a c:forEach, which iterates let's say from 20 to 24

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="20" end="24">
```

and inside it, another c:forEach

```
<c:forEach items="${'${i}'}" var="entry">
```

because I pass from controller multiple lists like this:

```
for(Team t : teams) {
String name = team.getTeamId() + "";
model.addObject(name, tableData);
}
```

where team is an object and model is a ModelAndView. The controller seems to work just fine, in my JSP I already used some data from it. But I can't get the items correctly.. I need to obtain items="20" when the i var is 20 and I really don't know what to try anymore. There are teams with id from 20 to 24, I've already checked and the error says either NumberFormatExceptions or Don't know how to iterate over the provided items..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to obtain items="20" in the second forEach, you can try this:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="20" end="24">
<c:set var="tmp" value="${i}">
<c:forEach items="${tmp}" var="entry">
    ...
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

but it seems that "items" must be an iterable data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing number to `JSTL foreach` so you have to use the `JSTL` format `taglib` to format the number. Because `JSTL` don't understood whether it is number or var.

Add below taglib on the `JSP`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Now pass the number to forach with formatting:

```
<c:forEach items="<fmt:formatNumber value="${i}"/>" var="entry">
```

Hope this will help you.